# Python3 script breaks with import error, REPL works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a small python script to get oauth2 token from a server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

payload = {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': 'username',
        'password': 'Somepassword',
        'scope': 'some',
        }

r = requests.post('https://example.com/oauth2/access_token',
        data=payload,
        params={'realm': '/services'},
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth('credential_name', 'credential_secret'))

print(r.json())
```

calling this on my ubuntu 16.04 machine with `python3 token.py` will throw an exception:

```
user on ~/Documents -> python3 token.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "token.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 34, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "/home/gkneitschel/Documents/token.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/auth.py", line 14, in <module>
    import threading
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 7, in <module>
    from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc
ImportError: cannot import name 'format_exc'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/queue.py", line 4, in <module>
    import threading
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 7, in <module>
    from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc
ImportError: cannot import name 'format_exc'
```

However, if I run this line by line in the REPL, it works fine.

If I just run `from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc`, this will break in the REPL as well.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 4.8.0-54-generic

Python: Python 3.5.2

Requests: requests (2.17.3)

Comment: rename it to something *other* than `token.py` (which is a name that's used in the standard library).

Comment: Well, that did the trick. It is working now. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad :-). You can now delete this q if you'd like.

Comment: Why deleting it? It might be useful to know, that a filename can break stuff. Or is it too specific?

Comment: This sort of question already exists (in many variations), unfortunately. I could, alternatively, dupe it to one (after I find it).